# Get the index of a list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have two list like this:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

By using `b` I want to get the result like this:

```
a -> 0, 2, 5
b -> 1, 4
c -> 3
d -> 6
```

Tried using `enumerate()`

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(b):
...     a[i]
... 
'a'
'b'
'a'
'c'
```

Didn't work.

Comment: In case you don't want to understand this code later: `[map(lambda pair: pair[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] == i, enumerate(a))) for i in b]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> [(char, [i for i,c in enumerate(a) if c==char]) for char in b]
[('a', [0, 2, 5]), ('b', [1, 4]), ('c', [3]), ('d', [6])]
```

or

```
>>> dict((char, [i for i,c in enumerate(a) if c==char]) for char in b)
{'a': [0, 2, 5], 'c': [3], 'b': [1, 4], 'd': [6]}
```

Answer (score 5):

[You were right to use enumerate, though you didn't quite use it exactly right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13826216/198633)

```
In [5]: a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']

In [6]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [7]: for char in b: print char, [i for i,c in enumerate(a) if c==char]
a [0, 2, 5]
b [1, 4]
c [3]
d [6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> indices = [ i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == b[0] ]
>>> indices
[0, 2, 5]
```

You can change `b[0]` to whatever letter you want the indices for.

**Explanation:**

Let each element of enumerate(a) be of the form `(i,x)`.
So, `indices` is an array of all `i` in enumerate(a) such that `x` equals `b[0]` (or whatever other letter you want it to be).

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_all_indexes(lst, item):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]

a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for item in b:
    print item, get_all_indexes(a, item)
```

Result:

```
>>> 
a [0, 2, 5]
b [1, 4]
c [3]
d [6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ll do it like...

**Code:**

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for item in b:
    print item + ':' + ','.join([str(i) for i,val in enumerate(a) if item==val])
```

**Output:**

```
a:0,2,5
b:1,4
c:3
d:6
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
def getIndex(ListA, ListB):
    res = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for element in ListB:
        for (i, v) in enumerate(ListA):
            if element == v:
                res[v].append(i)

    for key, value in sorted(res.items(), key = lambda d : d[0]):
        print(key, " -> ", ",".join([str(i) for i in value]))

a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
getIndex(a, b)
```

The output is：

```
a  ->  0,2,5
b  ->  1,4
c  ->  3
d  ->  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the enumerate :), here is something pretty interesting I found last time trying to answer something quite the same, that is to use `index()` function to return multiple positions.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for item in b:
    index = []
    start = -1
    while True:
        #also take care of the case where item in b is not in a
        try:
            start = a.index(item, start+1)
            index.append(start)
        except ValueError:
            break;
        print item, index
```

Result

```
a [0, 2, 5]
b [1, 4]
c [3]
d [6]
```

`a.index(b, position)` defines the starting point of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n+m)` algorithm (many other answers seem to have `O(n*m)` complexity):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,item in enumerate(a): D[item].append(i)  
>>> for item in b:
    print('{} -> {}'.format(item, D[item]))   

a -> [0, 2, 5]
b -> [1, 4]
c -> [3]
d -> [6]
```